# Apply kmeans calculated from a subset to full data

Tags: python, image-processing, k-means, image-segmentation

I have tomographic data sets I would like to segment into different parts via k-means clustering.
Since the dataset is quite large I calculate the k-means on a subset of the data.
Now I would like to apply the calculated k-means to a larger part of the dataset, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly, the segmentation is not correctly applied.

I load a subset of the images like this:

```
import glob
import imageio
import numpy
filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(FolderToRead, '*rec0*.tif'))
vol_subset = numpy.stack([imageio.imread(rec) for rec in filenames[::50]], 0)
```

The k-means clusters are then calculated like so:

```
import sklearn.cluster
kmeans_volume = sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=6, batch_size=2**11)
subset_clustered = kmeans_volume.fit_predict(numpy.array(vol_subset).reshape(-1,1))
subset_clustered.shape = numpy.shape(vol_subset)
```

The labeling looks great, label 1 being the bone, label 3 being an implant and label 5 being vessels in the bone.

```
for c, img in enumerate(subset_clustered):
    for d, cluster in enumerate(range(number_of_clusters)):
        plt.subplot(1, number_of_clusters, d+1)
        # Show original image
        plt.imshow(img)
        # Overlay label image
        plt.imshow(numpy.ma.masked_where(img != d, img), cmap='jet_r')
        plt.title('Image %s/%s, Label %s' % (c + 1, len(vol_clustered), d))
        plt.show()
```

[image: Labels applied to subset]

Now that I have calculated the k-means on a subset of the data I would like to apply them to the full dataset.
I tried to do this like so, but the labels don't seem to be consistent.

```
# Apply segmentation calculated above
for c, r in enumerate(reconstructions):
    # Read in all files subsequently
    reconstruction = imageio.imread(r)
    # Label the images with the kmeans calculated from a subset of the images
    clustered_rec = kmeans_volume.fit_predict(reconstruction.reshape(-1, 1))
    clustered_rec.shape = numpy.shape(reconstruction)
    # Write out the images
    imageio.imwrite('filename' + c + '.png, numpy.uint8(clustered_rec == 3) * 255 )  # 3 being the screw label
```

The image below shows a cropped output of the script above.
The vessels on one image on the left panel (the five blobs in the middle) are correctly labeled with 5, on the next image in the right panel they are labeled with 1, which is wrong...

[image: Wrongly applied labels]

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.
I hope I don't have to calculate the k-means on the full dataset, since there are 2700 TIFF images with a size of 1944x1944 pixels each...

Comment: Is it that the method `predict` have to be used instead of `fit_predict` on the full dataset?

Comment: @xdze2 That's *exactly* the case. Thanks a lot for spotting that! Can you add this as an answer, I'll then accept the answer.

Comment: CT typically has calibrated values, you can define fixed thresholds to distinguish bone from vessels and implants. You should not use k-means for this.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I'm perfectly aware of this. The machines were not calibrated, we have several different samples scanned at several energies and magnification settings. k-means segmentation is fairly robust to apply to all samples in our setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`MiniBatchKMeans`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html),  `fit_predict(X[, y])` both "**Compute cluster centers** and **predict** cluster index for each sample"

whereas the method `predict(X)`, only "**predict** the closest cluster each sample in X belongs to."
Therefore, only this one have to be used on the full dataset.